# Probability Series of events occuring in 10 years

Tags: probability

I have calculated the probability of $4$ events occurring independently on any given day as follows:
$a=.17, b=.05, c=.5$ and $d=.44$.  I think this gives me a probability of all of them occurring on the same day of $.002$ by multiplying them together.  Do I simply multiply $.002$ by $3,650$ to give me a probability that they will occur $6.83$ times in $10$ years?

Thanks